# PHPUnit Doctrine and PHP7

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony, php-7

I'm currently expierencing issues with phpunit on PHP7 with doctrine queries.

If I run them on the Development System they Pass without any issues.
But If I execute them on my Jenkins Build Server They fail with an segmentation fault.

Hears an example of the output:

```
    +PHPUnit 5.4.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET DoctrineNamespaceCacheKey[]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\User\User$CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\Company\Company$CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.first_name AS first_name_1, t0.last_name AS last_name_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.role AS role_4, t0.credentials_expire_date AS credentials_expire_date_5, t0.account_expire_date AS account_expire_date_6, t0.last_login AS last_login_7, t0.id AS id_8, t0.email_address AS email_address_9, t0.phone AS phone_10, t0.created AS created_11, t0.updated AS updated_12, t0.deletedAt AS deletedAt_13, t0.active AS active_14, t0.default_company_id AS default_company_id_15, t0.log_created_by AS log_created_by_16, t0.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_17 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [1] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\Acl\UserRoleMap$CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\User\U2FKey$CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\User\User\$GEDMO_TRANSLATABLE_CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET acl.1" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET acl.data" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET acl.actions" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\Acl\Role$CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\Acl\Role\$GEDMO_TREE_CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET DoctrineNamespaceCacheKey[]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [02813b2d6dfe9134ce2041e7bb276aed][1]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0, a0_.id AS id_1, a0_.name AS name_2, a0_.active AS active_3, a0_.created AS created_4, a0_.updated AS updated_5, a0_.tree_left AS tree_left_6, a0_.tree_level AS tree_level_7, a0_.tree_right AS tree_right_8, a0_.tree_root AS tree_root_9, a0_.parent_id AS parent_id_10, a0_.log_created_by AS log_created_by_11, a0_.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_12 FROM acl_role a0_ WHERE a0_.parent_id IS NULL [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [Project\Library\EntityBundle\Entity\Acl\Role\$GEDMO_TRANSLATABLE_CLASSMETADATA][2]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [fde6635bd67dc387082cbca14c42f757][1]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0, a0_.id AS id_1, a0_.name AS name_2, a0_.active AS active_3, a0_.created AS created_4, a0_.updated AS updated_5, a0_.tree_left AS tree_left_6, a0_.tree_level AS tree_level_7, a0_.tree_right AS tree_right_8, a0_.tree_root AS tree_root_9, a0_.parent_id AS parent_id_10, a0_.log_created_by AS log_created_by_11, a0_.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_12 FROM acl_role a0_ WHERE a0_.parent_id = ? [2] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [fde6635bd67dc387082cbca14c42f757][1]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0, a0_.id AS id_1, a0_.name AS name_2, a0_.active AS active_3, a0_.created AS created_4, a0_.updated AS updated_5, a0_.tree_left AS tree_left_6, a0_.tree_level AS tree_level_7, a0_.tree_right AS tree_right_8, a0_.tree_root AS tree_root_9, a0_.parent_id AS parent_id_10, a0_.log_created_by AS log_created_by_11, a0_.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_12 FROM acl_role a0_ WHERE a0_.parent_id = ? [3] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [fde6635bd67dc387082cbca14c42f757][1]" [] []
    [2016-06-19 22:55:50] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0, a0_.id AS id_1, a0_.name AS name_2, a0_.active AS active_3, a0_.created AS created_4, a0_.updated AS updated_5, a0_.tree_left AS tree_left_6, a0_.tree_level AS tree_level_7, a0_.tree_right AS tree_right_8, a0_.tree_root AS tree_root_9, a0_.parent_id AS parent_id_10, a0_.log_created_by AS log_created_by_11, a0_.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_12 FROM acl_role a0_ WHERE a0_.parent_id = ? [4] []
    Segmentation fault
```

I'm not really shure where this issue comes from.
But I'm having an suspision that it is caused by Doctrine/Symfony with PHPUnit and PHP7
But I don't really know where to look for.

**Update:**

Every Time it segfaults I get an line like this in the dmesg section:

```
[1729155.916967] traps: php[26512] general protection ip:70a8b3 sp:7ffe544fa660 error:0 in php7.0[400000+94f000]
```

These are the last lines I get when calling

strace phpunit

```
    lstat("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project Full Build/var/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parameter.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2561, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project Full Build/var/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    open("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project Full Build/var/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parameter.php", O_RDONLY) = 11
    fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2561, ...}) = 0
    fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2561, ...}) = 0
    fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2561, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 2561, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 11, 0) = 0x7f1929b66000
    munmap(0x7f1929b66000, 2561)            = 0
    close(11)                               = 0
    lstat("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project Full Build/var/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/ParameterTypeInferer.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2289, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project Full Build/var/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    open("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project Full Build/var/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/ParameterTypeInferer.php", O_RDONLY) = 11
    fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2289, ...}) = 0
    fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2289, ...}) = 0
    fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2289, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 2289, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 11, 0) = 0x7f1929b66000
    munmap(0x7f1929b66000, 2289)            = 0
    close(11)                               = 0
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
    sendto(6, "*2\r\n$3\r\nGET\r\n$37\r\n[fde6635bd67dc"..., 57, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 57
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$", 1, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 1
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$1496\r\n\0\0\0\2\27\37Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 1505
    write(9, "[2016-06-21 21:39:48] snc_redis."..., 106[2016-06-21 21:39:48] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [fde6635bd67dc387082cbca14c42f757][1]" [] []
    ) = 106
    write(10, "[2016-06-21 21:39:48] doctrine.D"..., 464[2016-06-21 21:39:48] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0, a0_.id AS id_1, a0_.name AS name_2, a0_.active AS active_3, a0_.created AS created_4, a0_.updated AS updated_5, a0_.tree_left AS tree_left_6, a0_.tree_level AS tree_level_7, a0_.tree_right AS tree_right_8, a0_.tree_root AS tree_root_9, a0_.parent_id AS parent_id_10, a0_.log_created_by AS log_created_by_11, a0_.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_12 FROM acl_role a0_ WHERE a0_.parent_id = ? [2] []
    ) = 464
    sendto(4, "\243\1\0\0\3SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0"..., 423, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 423
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "\1\0\0\1\r5\0\0\2\3def\10yoda_dev\3a0_\10acl_r"..., 48, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 48
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "n\f?\0\1\0\0\0\1\1\0\0\0\0/\0\0\3\3def\10yoda_dev\3"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "d\f?\0\23\0\0\0\f\201\20\0\0\0=\0\0\10\3def\10yoda_dev\3"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "yoda_dev\3a0_\10acl_role\fparent_id_"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "1\5\0\0\21\376\0\0\2\0", 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 10
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
    sendto(6, "*2\r\n$3\r\nGET\r\n$37\r\n[fde6635bd67dc"..., 57, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 57
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$", 1, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 1
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$1496\r\n\0\0\0\2\27\37Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 1505
    write(9, "[2016-06-21 21:39:48] snc_redis."..., 106[2016-06-21 21:39:48] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [fde6635bd67dc387082cbca14c42f757][1]" [] []
    ) = 106
    write(10, "[2016-06-21 21:39:48] doctrine.D"..., 464[2016-06-21 21:39:48] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0, a0_.id AS id_1, a0_.name AS name_2, a0_.active AS active_3, a0_.created AS created_4, a0_.updated AS updated_5, a0_.tree_left AS tree_left_6, a0_.tree_level AS tree_level_7, a0_.tree_right AS tree_right_8, a0_.tree_root AS tree_root_9, a0_.parent_id AS parent_id_10, a0_.log_created_by AS log_created_by_11, a0_.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_12 FROM acl_role a0_ WHERE a0_.parent_id = ? [3] []
    ) = 464
    sendto(4, "\243\1\0\0\3SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0"..., 423, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 423
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "\1\0\0\1\r5\0\0\2\3def\10yoda_dev\3a0_\10acl_r"..., 277, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 277
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "\0\23\0\0\0\f\201\20\0\0\0009\0\0\7\3def\10yoda_dev\3a0_"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "v\3a0_\10acl_role\vtree_root_9\ttree_"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "ad only\0011\0232016-05-08 00:28:42\02320"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 152
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
    sendto(6, "*2\r\n$3\r\nGET\r\n$37\r\n[fde6635bd67dc"..., 57, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 57
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$", 1, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 1
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$1496\r\n\0\0\0\2\27\37Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 1505
    write(9, "[2016-06-21 21:39:48] snc_redis."..., 106[2016-06-21 21:39:48] snc_redis.INFO: Executing command "GET [fde6635bd67dc387082cbca14c42f757][1]" [] []
    ) = 106
    write(10, "[2016-06-21 21:39:48] doctrine.D"..., 464[2016-06-21 21:39:48] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0, a0_.id AS id_1, a0_.name AS name_2, a0_.active AS active_3, a0_.created AS created_4, a0_.updated AS updated_5, a0_.tree_left AS tree_left_6, a0_.tree_level AS tree_level_7, a0_.tree_right AS tree_right_8, a0_.tree_root AS tree_root_9, a0_.parent_id AS parent_id_10, a0_.log_created_by AS log_created_by_11, a0_.log_updated_by AS log_updated_by_12 FROM acl_role a0_ WHERE a0_.parent_id = ? [4] []
    ) = 464
    sendto(4, "\243\1\0\0\3SELECT a0_.admin AS admin_0"..., 423, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 423
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "\1\0\0\1\r5\0\0\2\3def\10yoda_dev\3a0_\10acl_r"..., 135, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 135
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "acl_role\6name_2\4name\f\10\0\377\0\0\0\375\1\0\0\0"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "\10yoda_dev\3a0_\10acl_role\ftree_leve"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "\21log_created_by_11\16log_created_b"..., 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 287
    poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(4, "\0\2\0", 287, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 3
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
    sendto(6, "*2\r\n$3\r\nGET\r\n$37\r\n[fde6635bd67dc"..., 57, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 57
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$", 1, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 1
    poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
    recvfrom(6, "$1496\r\n\0\0\0\2\27\37Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 1505
    --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0} ---
    +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
    Segmentation fault
```

can anybody tell me where this comes from?
I'f I run it before calling composer update it seems to work, as far as I can tell. But after it it wont.
So it doesn't actually seem to be an core issue, more an plugin issue so I'm currently looking into it deeper

Comment: Segmentation faults are caused by internal programming error: Report it https://bugs.php.net

Comment: Ok, just found something interessting.

Comment: If I update the packages I get segmentation fault as well in the dev Environment, which is quite strange. Seems to be an bug in the doctrine component.
I will attach an strace to the message above, maybe you can see the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok
the next part is going to be really strange.
I enabled the following moduls as these where the only ones missing:

xdebug

I reconfigured the opcache.ini file to the following settings

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.memory_consumption = 2048
opcache.enable_cli = On
opcache.file_cache /tmp/php
```

After this it always executes.
Even If I remove these lines.
No matter what I do, I can't reproduce it.
This is really frustrating but at least it works.

If somebody can enlite me, I'm really gratefull.